# Accessing bigquery API from an embedded device

Tags: rest, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I intend to load data to BigQuery from an embedded device through the REST API.

1. My BigQuery initialization is complete, and I am accessing the same with python libraries.
2. My embedded device creates the JWT using these parameters hashed with my service account JSON

```
{
      "iss": "*account*@*project*.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
      "iat": "*thistime*",
      "exp": "*time +20mins*",
      "aud": "https://bigquery.googleapis.com",
      "sub": "*account*@*project*.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

3. My HTTP request

```
curl -X GET -H 'Authorization: Bearer *my JWT*' -H 'content-type: application/json' -v -i 'https://bigquery.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/*project*/datasets/*dataset*?key=*API Key*'
```

I tried to test the same using a TCP terminal application
Please explain to me if there is anything wrong with the formulation.

1. I need to know first whether BigQuery permits such an access.
2. please tell me what should be the *sub* in the JSON string.
3. Please point me to the correct procedure if I am doing wrong.

I refer to this post, but can't do the same in my scenario:

[Google Cloud Storage JSON API with JWT Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54563751/google-cloud-storage-json-api-with-jwt-token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edited]
Have a look at this link for configuring authentication model for the embedded device - https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#jwt-auth

1. Create a service account and download the json key file.
2. Create the JWT token. I used PyJWT library to create one.
   As per the documentation, fill the JWT fields in this python file and then run it:

```
import time, jwt
iat = time.time()
exp = iat + 3600
PRIVATE_KEY_ID_FROM_JSON = "<private_key_id from json key file>"
PRIVATE_KEY_FROM_JSON = "<private_key from json file>"
payload = {'iss': '<client_email field from json key file>',
           'sub': '<client_email field from json key file>',
           'aud': 'https://bigquery.googleapis.com/',
           'iat': iat,
           'exp': exp}
additional_headers = {'kid': PRIVATE_KEY_ID_FROM_JSON}
signed_jwt = jwt.encode(payload, PRIVATE_KEY_FROM_JSON, headers=additional_headers,algorithm='RS256')
print(signed_jwt)
```

3. Test a BigQuery API

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <generated JWT>" https://bigquery.googleapis.
com/bigquery/v2/projects/<GCP project name>/datasets/<test dataset name>
```

Comment: Sir,
I am using python libraries to test the environment, and it seems working.
Now I need to do the same with an embedded device.
STM32 microcontroller and a GSM module.

So I need to use the REST API

Comment: @Noby - I have edited the response to use REST API only.

Comment: @Noby - https://medium.com/@suds123/bigquery-rest-api-call-using-jwt-323c499932b2 - Let me know if it worked for you. If so then accept this answer.

Comment: @Noby - I've tried this myself and I can confirm that it works. A couple of details worth mentioning:

1) Service account JSON files contain the "private_key" value as: "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n......"  Make sure to include the full string in "PRIVATE_KEY_FROM_JSON".

2) Python script will return the JWT in the format of: b'eyJ0eXAiOiJ.........', but make sure to only provide the token eyJ0eXAiOiJ........ (without the b and '') in the Authorization: Bearer, otherwise it won't be recognized properly and it will fail with 401 error.

Try it and please consider accepting Suds's answer.

Comment: @Suds
Sir,
A big thanks to you. It worked for me as I tried from an API builder site.

Now experimenting with the SSL stack of my device.