# Google Cloud - Accessing Storage API with JWT token: Illegal URI error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to make a JWT call to storage API using the example listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/service-account-authentication#making_an_authenticated_request) with some changes as below -

```
def generate_jwt():

"""Generates a signed JSON Web Token using a Google API Service Account."""

now = int(time.time())
sa_email = os.environ["FUNCTION_IDENTITY"]
expiry_length = 3600

# build payload
payload = {
    'iat': now,
    # expires after 'expiry_length' seconds.
    "exp": now + expiry_length,
    # iss must match 'issuer' in the security configuration in your
    # swagger spec (e.g. service account email). It can be any string.
    'iss': sa_email,
    # aud must be either your Endpoints service name, or match the value
    # specified as the 'x-google-audience' in the OpenAPI document.
    'aud': "https://storage.googleapis.com", 
    # sub and email should match the service account's email address
    'sub': sa_email,
    'email': sa_email
    
}
# sign with keyfile
sa_keyfile="cred.json"
signer = google.auth.crypt.RSASigner.from_service_account_file(sa_keyfile)
jwt = google.auth.jwt.encode(signer, payload)
return jwt
```

and calliing it here

```
def make_jwt_request(signed_jwt, url="https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/BUCKET_NAME"):
"""Makes an authorized request to the endpoint"""
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(signed_jwt.decode('utf-8')),
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    "Host": "www.googleapis.com",
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(response.status_code, response.content)
response.raise_for_status()
```

but getting error as Couldn't parse the specified URI. Illegal URI.

I dont understand why it is a illegal URI. I tried with https://googleapis.com/storage/b/BUCKETNMAE but still same error. could not find anything on SO or google docs about this. any idea what wrong am I doing here ?

Comment: Google Cloud Storage does not accept a Signed JWT for authorization. Once you create the Signed JWT you must exchange the JWT for an Access Token. Refer to my answer here on how to do this in Python. Review my function `exchangeJwtForAccessToken()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564901/8016720

Comment: @JohnHanley  -  thank you, just a follow up question- is it possible to have Storage bucket identified based on a authenticated token. The reason is I don't want to hardcode bucket name in here?

Comment: Access Tokens grant access based upon scopes. You cannot embed the bucket name within the token. You must specify the bucket name via the API endpoint. Bucket names are global public names.

Comment: @JohnHanley could you please add your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to upvote your answer

Comment: @vicalderon - thank you, answer posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Cloud Storage does not accept a Signed JWT for authorization. Once you create the Signed JWT you must exchange the JWT for an Access Token.

Refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54564901/8016720) or my [article](https://www.jhanley.com/google-cloud-creating-oauth-access-tokens-for-rest-api-calls/) for a complete example in Python.

```
def exchangeJwtForAccessToken(signed_jwt):
    '''
    This function takes a Signed JWT and exchanges it for a Google OAuth Access Token
    '''

    auth_url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"

    params = {
        "grant_type": "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
        "assertion": signed_jwt
    }

    r = requests.post(auth_url, data=params)

    if r.ok:
        return(r.json()['access_token'], '')

    return None, r.text
```